# WPF Grid doesn't fire mouse events when invisible, even though the mouse is capured

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, mouseevent, hidden

In my WPF application I have a Grid with MouseDown, MouseUp and MouseMove events. I want the grid to disappear whenever I press the left mouse button, and reappear when I release it. The problem is that I don't get any mouse events while the grid is invisible (Visibility.Hidden).

This is the MouseDown handler:

```
private void TabHeaderOnMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    tabHeader.CaptureMouse();
    tabHeader.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

And the MouseUp handler:

```
private void TabHeaderOnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    tabHeader.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    tabHeader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: Set `Opacity = 0` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Opacity to 0 instead of changing the Visibility solved my problem.